# Emitted object from child to parent is undefined when accessing properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs2

I've implemented a simple custom event defined below. However, whenever I get values emitted back to the parent, accessing its properties gives undefined. Im pretty clueless to why...

```
<!-- Parent Component function -->
onAddExercise(
  workoutIndex: number,
  workoutRoundIndex: number,
  exercise: ExerciseModel
) {
   console.log(exercise); outputs the whole object with values
   console.log(exercise.id); undefined!
   console.log(exercise.name); undefined!
}
```

/

```
<-- Render Child Component in Parent -->
<ExerciseSearch @onAddExercise="onAddExercise" 
                :workoutIndex="wIndex" 
                :workoutRoundIndex="wrIndex" 
/>
```

/

```
<-- Child Component function -->
async onSelectExercise(exerciseId: string) {
 var response = await this.$apollo.query({
   query: EXERCISE,
   variables: {
     id: exerciseId
   }
 });
 let exercise = response.data as ExerciseModel
 console.log(exercise); outputs the whole object with values
 console.log(exercise.id); outputs the id
 console.log(exercise.name); outputs the name

 <!-- Emit to Parent with payload -->
 this.$emit(
    "onAddExercise",
    this.workoutIndex,
    this.workoutRoundIndex,
    exercise 
  );
}
```

**Update**

I used dubugger to get the current state and set return type to any just in case.
[image]

Comment: Is setting the type as `ExerciseModel` doing something unexpected here? Assuming the output of `console.log(excercise)` is something like `{id: '123', name: 'test'}`.

Comment: @ebbishop Check updated question :)

Comment: well your screenshot from debugger shows that variable `exercise` contains object with property `exercise`. However its not clear how that happened because code you posted looks ok....

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/), [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or something like that ?